# iPhone Icon file in bundle blank when building for App store distribution

Tags: iphone, icons

I have been spinning my wheels for a couple hours on why when I build my app with my distribution cert with the device as the target the Icon.png file in the bundle is empty.  If I build with my developer cert or against the simulator the Icon.png in the bundle matches the one in my project file.  I have verified my Icon.png is 57X57, has no alpha channel, had extra finder attributes removed.  I even took one of the Icon.png files from my first application that is in the store today, and it didn't work either.

Here is the output from the build results:

> CopyPNGFile build/Distribution-iphoneos/myApp.app/Icon.png Icon.png
>   cd /Users/wrbarbour/projects/myAppTWO/myApp
>   setenv COPY_COMMAND /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/pbxcp
>   setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>   "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/iPhoneOS Build System Support.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/copypng" -compress "" /Users/wrbarbour/projects/myAppTWO/myApp/Icon.png /Users/wrbarbour/projects/myAppTWO/myApp/build/Distribution-iphoneos/myApp.app/Icon.png

Can someone get me pointed in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!   The files are not empty, they are just compressed using some non-standard compression.  If you open your project properties and search for 'Compress PNG Files', you will see a box that is checked.   If you un-check that the images will show up inside the bundle with finder.   They *should* work fine with UIKit if they are compressed or not but if your images are really not showing up on the device, uncheck it.  If they are compressed they will appear blank in Finder / Preview.

Comment: Just curious - did you PNG's turn out to be corrupted from the Compression or was it just that Finder did not see them?

Comment: Something like this happened to me.  The icon would show up in the simulator, but not on my iPod Touch.  Unchecking Compress PNG Files fixed it.  The icon must have been saved strangely or something.